# Quadrotor without physics

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, quadcopter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm sorry for my bad english.

I need to create a quadrotor simulator with an arm, but I don't want to simulate the physics. At the moment I'm control quadrotor changging model state through ROS. I think that If I turn disable the gravity in my model when I'll try to take anything with an arm in quadrotor, the simulation probably don't work well.

¿Does anybody know if it is posible?

Thanks for your atention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57873/quadrotor-without-physics/) by [Jonathan Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4379/jonathan-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-12**:
Are you using gazebo, or is this some other simulator?

**Comment by [Jonathan Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4379/jonathan-ruiz/) on 2013-03-19**:
Yes, I'm using gazebo. I based my quadrotor in "hector_quadrotor" stack it works well. But I have another problem with gazebo, I posted it in: http://answers.ros.org/question/58669/problem-with-two-joints-in-arm/ thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can pause the physic engine by writing "rosservice call gazebo/pause_physics" on the terminal. look at gazebo tutorials for other options.

---

Originally posted by [brkk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4761/brkk/) with karma: 70 on 2013-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1